# Why won't Select work on my Dynamic values?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Why won't `Select` work on my list of `Dynamic` values?

For example if I have some `Dynamic` values in a list that I attempt to select using `Select` as, in

```
Manipulate[
 { 
   Dynamic@p[[#]] & /@ Range[5],
   Select[Dynamic@p[[#]] & /@ Range[5], (#[[1]] != #[[2]]) &]
 } // TableForm,
 {p, None},
 {{np, "", "Test"}, Column[{Dynamic[sP /@ Range[5] // Row, TrackedSymbols :> {np}]}] &},

 Initialization :> (
   np = 5;
   sP[i_] := With[{j = i}, 
     Slider2D[Dynamic[p[[j]]], {1, 26, 1}, 
      Appearance -> "Tiny", ImageSize -> {25, 25}, ImageMargins -> 0]];
   p = ConstantArray[{1, 1}, 5];  )]
```

I repeatedly get errors like

> Part 2 of {1,1} does not exist

for each element in the list (which doesn't even make any sense).

Is there some other idiom for selecting from a list of items that are `Dynamic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work if I remove the extraneous calls to `Dynamic`.

```
Manipulate[
  {p[[#]] & /@ Range[5], 
   Select[p[[#]] & /@ Range[5], (#[[1]] != #[[2]]) &]} // TableForm,
  {p, None}, 
  {{np, "", "Test"}, 
  Column[{Dynamic[sP /@ Range[5] // Row, TrackedSymbols :> {np}]}] &},
  Initialization :> (
    np = 5;
    sP[i_] := 
      With[{j = i}, 
        Slider2D[Dynamic[p[[j]]], {1, 26, 1}, 
          Appearance -> "Tiny", 
          ImageSize -> {25, 25}, 
          ImageMargins -> 0]];
   p = ConstantArray[{1, 1}, 5];)]
```

[image: demo]

#### Update

I found one more `Dynamic` to eliminate

```
Manipulate[
  {p[[#]] & /@ Range[5], 
   Select[p[[#]] & /@ Range[5], (#[[1]] != #[[2]]) &]} // TableForm,
  {p, None}, 
  {{np, "", "Test"}, Row[sP /@ Range[5]] &},
  Initialization :> (
    np = 5;
    sP[i_] := 
      With[{j = i}, 
        Slider2D[Dynamic[p[[j]]], {1, 26, 1}, 
          Appearance -> "Tiny", 
          ImageSize -> {25, 25}, 
          ImageMargins -> 0]];
   p = ConstantArray[{1, 1}, 5];)]
```

Comment: I guess I was being too dynamic. How do I know which ones are extraneous (a constant source of confusion: sorting out when `Dynamic` is needed, especially within `Manipulate`).

Comment: Interesting that this change also has the side effect of allowing `TableForm` to affect the elements of the list too (so they appear as stacked values rather than as a list).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. It can be difficult. I always start by assuming that a control variable explicitly defined in a manipulate will not need to wrapped in `Dynamic`. I only add `Dynamic` wrappers when my assumption proves to be false.

Comment: Good heuristic. I'll try to remember it next time.